# DeferredFileOutputStream not creating the file if the file size is lesser than threshold size limit

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

I am using the DeferredFileOutputStream to write files to disk. I have specified the size threshold to 10K, sometimes if the file size is less than the threshold, then files are not getting into physical location. I think its holding in-memory.
In this scenario do i need to explicitly write to disk?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(
               "atest.zip"));
         DeferredFileOutputStream differedFileOutputStream = new DeferredFileOutputStream(1, new File(
               "atest.zip"));
         ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(differedFileOutputStream);
         String file5Name = "folder/android.pdf";
         String file1Name = "file1.txt";
         String file2Name = "file2.txt";
         String file3Name = "folder/file3.txt";
         String file4Name = "folder/file4.txt";

         addToZipFile(file1Name, zos);
         addToZipFile(file2Name, zos);
         addToZipFile(file3Name, zos);
         addToZipFile(file4Name, zos);
         zos.close();
         differedFileOutputStream.close();
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }
public static void addToZipFile(String fileName, ZipOutputStream zos) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
      System.out.println("Writing '" + fileName + "' to zip file");
      File file = new File(fileName);
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
      ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
      zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

      byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
      int length;
      while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
         zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
      }

      zos.closeEntry();
      fis.close();
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream.html):

> An output stream which will retain data in memory until a specified threshold is reached, and only then commit it to disk. If the stream is closed before the threshold is reached, the data **will not be written to disk at all**.

And then it explains the use case for this class:

> This class originated in FileUpload processing. In this use case, you do not know in advance the size of the file being uploaded. If the file is small you want to store it in memory (for speed), but if the file is large you want to store it to file (to avoid memory issues).

So the answer is no, the file doesn't get written. It sounds that you shouldn't be using this at all if you are trying to write to disk in every case. You should just use FileOutputStream directly.

Answer (score 0):

Thats right. The solution i found was, After i right all the files, check if the Threshold reached, if No, then write the file to OutputStream explicitly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(
               "atest.zip"));
         DeferredFileOutputStream differedFileOutputStream = new DeferredFileOutputStream(1, new File(
               "atest.zip"));
         ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(differedFileOutputStream);
         String file5Name = "folder/android.pdf";
         String file1Name = "file1.txt";
         String file2Name = "file2.txt";
         String file3Name = "folder/file3.txt";
         String file4Name = "folder/file4.txt";

         addToZipFile(file1Name, zos);
         addToZipFile(file2Name, zos);
         addToZipFile(file3Name, zos);
         addToZipFile(file4Name, zos);



  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                   "atest.zip"));
    if(differedFileOutputStream.isInMemory()) {
                differedFileOutputStream.writeTo(fos);
             }
         zos.close();
         differedFileOutputStream.close();
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }
```